# Filter files globally in the Documents and Media portlet in Liferay

Tags: java, liferay, portlet, liferay-6

I have my Liferay organizations set up like this:

```
North America
      |
   |     |
 Dept1  Dept2
```

What I would like to do is allow Dept1 and Dept2 to view any documents posted in North America (as read only), but prevent Dept1 from viewing Dept2's documents and vice versa.

For example, a vacation request form will be posted in North America that both Dept1 and Dept2 should be able to read but not modify. However, if Dept1 posts a sign up sheet for the Dept1 golf tournament, Dept2 should not be able to view this.

I've successfully managed to set up something similar to this by creating multiple sites, but I'd to be able to view all these files in the same portlet rather than the user having to switch between their Dept site and the North American site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I've implemented something similar myself (this is the only way I could figure out how to do this).

1) Create two Regular Roles, one for each department

[image]

2) Assign the appropriate new roles to each user

[image]

[image]

3) Within Documents and Media create your documents/media/folders (e.g. Dept. 1 Files / Dept. 2 Files folders)

[image]

4) Define their permissions - see above image for where to click - (e.g. for Dept. 1 Files folder uncheck everything for the Department 2 role, also make sure guest can't do stuff)

[image]

5) For the global folder (North America), just set the permissions so both roles can have full permissions

Hope I've understood you correctly and this helps.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I need. Out of curiosity, can something similar be done with calendar entries?

Comment: Awesome! I think that each Organization has their own Calendar, not sure about having 'North America' entries where both Departments can view. Will have a look later on today.

Comment: This thread might be of use, https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/5598720. It looks like this functionality has to be implemented by ourselves at the moment.